# Ubuntu 13.04 Window Title Font

Tags: customization, window, fonts

How can I change the font for the window title in 13.04 Ubuntu?

---

Original text:

Wie kann ich die Schrift für den Fenstertitel bei Ubuntu 13.04 ändern?

Answer (score 2):

Download Unity tweak tool in the software center. This app let's you adjust your fonts in appearance --> fonts.

Comment: Thank you...now i have the correct font for Windows Title.

Comment: You're welcome! I'd rather have a 'This answer is usefull' then a thank you though ;-)